# How do I override the default animation on a bootstrap 4 collapse menu?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to override the default slide down animation of Bootstrap 4's collapse element.

When you click the button to open a collapsed element I'd like the element to 3d rotate in instead of slide down as per the normal bootstrap 4 transition.

Here's what I've done so far: https://codepen.io/tasmaniaman/pen/LYNMOdy

CSS:

```
<style>
  .collapse:not(.show),
  .collapse {
      display:block;
      visibility:visible;
  }
  .collapsing {
      -webkit-transition: none;
      transition: none;
    }
  .collapse {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);
      transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);
      -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
      -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
      transform-origin: 50% 0;
      -webkit-transition: 1s transform ease-in;
      -o-transition: 1s transform ease-in;
      transition: 1s transform ease-in;
  }
  .collapse.show {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: 1s transform ease-out;
      -o-transition: 1s transform ease-out;
      transition: 1s transform ease-out;
  }
</style>
```

When you click the button in the codepen example the element quickly appears because I've overridden the default transition on the collapsing class and when you click it again the element correctly 3d rotates out.

I'd like the same 3d rotation when the elements appears. Any help from bootstrap 4 / css gurus would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've worked it out @ahmad - see codepen: https://codepen.io/tasmaniaman/pen/LYNMOdy

```
.flip {
  -webkit-transition: .25s transform ease-in-out !important;
  -o-transition: .25s transform ease-in-out !important;
  transition: .25s transform ease-in-out !important;
  display: block !important;
  visibility: visible;
}
.collapse.show {  
  -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0);
  transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition: .25s transform ease-in-out !important;
  -o-transition: .25s transform ease-in-out !important;
  transition: .25s transform ease-in-out !important;
}
.collapsing {
  height: auto !important;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);
  transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition: .25s transform ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s transform ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s transform ease-in-out; 
}
.collapse:not(.show) {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);
  transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition: .25s transform ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s transform ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s transform ease-in-out; 
}

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 shadow-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          Open Sesame
        </button>
        <div class="flip collapse rounded-0" id="collapseExample">
          <div class="card card-body bg-secondary rounded-0">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, buddy. I fixed it for you. Note that `.collapsing` is the class that we should change in order to get the same transition on the way back. So I had to override some properties. Using `!important` and the code won't work without it. Since bootstrap is using javascript to perform the transition.

`.collpasing` is using hight and transition to make it comes from the top to the bottom and return from bottom to top. Therefore I did override the hight and made it into `auto`

Also to make the transition happen from the exact place it has to use `transform-origin` if you remove it from `collapsing` it will look like a flipped card kinda.

On top of that the transition must be overridden using `!important` without it you can not apply your custom transition.

lastly based upon your code. You MUST keep the `!important` used in the following classes.

```
.collapse:not(.show),
.collapse
```

without it, it will disappear.

```css
.collapse:not(.show),
.collapse {
  display: block !important;
  visibility: visible;
}

.collapse.show {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);
  transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition: 1s transform ease-in;
  -o-transition: 1s transform ease-in;
  transition: 1s transform ease-in;
}

.collapsing {
  height: auto !important;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0);
  transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition: 1s transform ease-out !important;
  -o-transition: 1s transform ease-out !important;
  transition: 1s transform ease-out !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          Button with data-target
        </button>
      <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="card card-body bg-secondary">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: You are a legend Ahmad, thanks! Is there a way to have the collapsed element start from the collapsed state? With your code it starts in the visible state. Thanks again! :-)

I worked it out. 

If I add the show class to:

`<div class="collapse show" id="collapseExample">`

 it starts collapsed.

Funny thing is that the code now has the show class when the element is collapsed and the show class is removed when its showing. Maybe we need to flip the CSS around a bit?

What do you think?

I updated the code pen: https://codepen.io/tasmaniaman/pen/LYNMOdy

Comment: I worked it out. 

If I add the show class to:

`<div class="collapse show" id="collapseExample">`

 it starts collapsed.

Funny thing is that the code now has the show class when the element is collapsed and the show class is removed when its showing. Maybe we need to flip the CSS around a bit?

What do you think?

I updated the code pen: https://codepen.io/tasmaniaman/pen/LYNMOdy

Comment: Looks good to me. OR do you want it to be hidden and show up only when the user clicks on the button.??

Comment: Hey Armad, Yes. It should default to hidden then show up when a user clicks - when they click a second time it should disappear. :-)